# Multiple Ship and tracking codes

Tags: shipping, shipment, shipment-tracking, status

I'm working on a store where they do not always have the product right away, sometimes they have to produce it.

So they asked for a function that would be like this:

imagine there's a order, the customer ordered 3 products, **X, Y and Z**.

They have **product X** in stock, so they want to ship it, but **products Y and Z** will be produced, so they will generate 1 or two more shipping.
And they would like to decide when to change status to complete, in this case it will be only after all products are delivered.

Right now after we sent the first tracking code it changes automatically to Complete.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is already possible with Magento. When you ship the available items, you need to make sure the items that are not available are set to 0.  Once they are received (or in your case produced) you can then ship them 1 at a time or all together.

You can then invoice after all products have been shipped.

You can also set a custom order status to let your clients know what the status is by creating a new option such as "producing product" under `System->Order Statuses`

Comment: Hi, SR_Magento, thank you for the answer.

Comment: Hi, SR_Magento, thank you for the answer.

But what I need is to have a way to create an status everytime I generate a ship.

Exemple: 1st ship generated = Ship 1 / 2nd ship generated = Ship 2, until I have the last one, that will change status to complete.

The invoice is generated automatically by my payment method.

Thanks!